# Restoring mysql data from *.IBD file

Tags: mysql, restore

Unfortunately I have recently lost my VPS and the provider restore it after 1 week, then the only things that I had was the raw files on my server which were accessible in recovery mode.

so by moving those files from the server to my local machine and the other new server which I have bought, I need to recover those IBD files to the MySQL.

What I have to do with these *.IBD files in order to have my data on a live mysql service again?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I wanted to restore my data on another database rather than the live one.

First of all you should take all of your old data from the following location on your old server and move them to your new VPS. 
old destination would be:

```
/var/lib/mysql/your_db_name
```

so I created another database called `new_db`  then start to creating the tables by the `CREATE TABLE` statement that I had from my live database, maybe you can find them in your codes.

by doing these, you will have all your tables but empty ones.

let’s assume that you placed the old data files in the:

```
/location/to/old_files/
```

and
you created a new empty database called `new_db`.

this is time to restoring your old data, please follow next steps for each one of your tables:

1. discarding new data file from its structure by executing
   following command on the mysql  where has access to your new
   database `new_db`:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE my_table DISCARD TABLESPACE;
   ```
2. coping the old data files to the same table structure but in
   the new database location:

```
CP /location/to/old_files/my_table.ibd /var/lib/mysql/new_db/my_table.ibd
```

3. change the ownership of the ids file which recently copied in the
   new database should be changed to `mysql:mysql`:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/new_db/my_table.ibd
```

4. finally, you can execute this command where you executed the previous one:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

it works for me.

Comment: When I first tried to import the table I got this error: _#1808 - Schema mismatch (Table has ROW_TYPE_DYNAMIC row format, .ibd file has ROW_TYPE_COMPACT row format)._ So I added `ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT DEFAULT` to the `CREATE TABLE` script. Now I have another error: _ERROR 1808 (HY000): Schema mismatch (Clustered index validation failed. Because the .cfg file is missing, table definition of the IBD file could be different. Or the data file itself is already corrupted.)_ Have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: What if mysql says: _Unknown table 'my_table'_ ?

Comment: @Néstor please note that I mentioned, you need to create those table as an empty table => `and you created a new empty database called new_db.`